# Swift updating child array updates parent array as well

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop, model

Here is my code.

I have one model, which consist array of another model.

```
class MyModel{
 var arrSubModel = [SubModel]()
}

class SubModel{
 var value1 = String()
 var value2 = String()
}
```

Now in my class I have 2 variables for holding array of MyModel.

```
class MyVC:UIViewController {
    var arrMyModel = [MyModel1,MyModel2,MyModel3]
    var arrFilterModel = []

    func filter() {
        arrFilterModel = []

        for model in arrMyModel {
            for subModel in model.arrSubModel {
                if conditionMet {
                    //doNothing
                } else {
                    //remove that subModel
                    model.arrSubModel.removeObject(subModel)
                }
            }
            arrFilterModel.append(model)
        }
    }
}
```

but when I access `arrMyModel` again, `arrSubModel` is removed from it but it should be only removed from `arrFilterModel`.

I think I'm doing something wrong.
Hope you guys can help.

Thank you.

Comment: Your indentation is drunk.

Comment: You should never remove/insert an element from/to an array when you do a for-loop on that array (`model.arrSubModel`). You will have unexpected behaviors/contents.

Comment: What're you trying to achieve exactly? What's an example input and an example output?

Comment: Your code is really hard to read because you have generalized it so much. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @CodeDifferent, So basically I am trying to filter `arrMyModel` depending on some conditions and setting it to `arrFilterModel`.
Everything works fine when I filter String,Int etc variables on `arrMyModel`.
But when I change array inside `arrFilterModel` it updates array inside `arrMyModel` as well, hope it makes everything clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question would be much simpler to answer if you expressed your intent more clearly

- Your code is incredibly hard to read because of the crazy indentation
- Your code is incredibly hard to understand because of its over-generalization
- Your code isn't following Swift's doctrine of immutability and pure functions.

From what I can gather, you want `arrFilterModel` to be set to a subset of `arrMyModel` depending on some condition, without effecting the original `arrMyModel`.

There's a much simpler way of doing what you're trying to do:

```
func giveMeABetterName() { //don't call it "filter", it's meaningless.
   let copy = arrMyModel
   let arrFilterModel = copy.map{$0.arrSubMode}.filter{$0 == foo} //substitute in the condition
}
```

I would recommend you change this to not abuse object state, and to use params/returns instead:

```
func giveMeABetterName(source: [MyModel]) -> [SubModel] {
    return source.map{$0.arrSubMode}.filter{$0 == foo} //substitute in the condition
}
```

You're also suffering from the unintentional data sharing that comes from the reference semantics of classes. Switching to the value semantics of structs will fix this.

Comment: I tried both solutions, This still changing my `arrMyModel`.

Comment: One thing to note is everything works fine until I update array Inside `arrFilterModel`.
When I update array inside `arrFilterModel` it updates array inside `arrMyModel` as well.

Comment: @ZaidPathan Oh, that's because you're using Classes and not Structs.

Comment: Yes changing Model from Class to Struct worked, thanks a ton brother!
Please update your answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: @ZaidPathan I think you're lacking understanding of reference vs value semantics, and classes vs structs. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-ID82

Comment: You may not believe me but I had tried with struct as well, but at that time it didn't work, might be I was doing something wrong in that as well.

Comment: I see you're from a Java background. I would like to emphasize that Swift does many things differently, and although Java style programming is definitely possible, it should be avoided. I strongly suggest you refactor this function to be a static, pure function, that doesn't rely on object state

Comment: I see, thank you for the details, I will keep in mind and explore more of it.